# Problems with json.parse when making a command in discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to code a Cursedimage subreddit command and I keep getting this error

(node:10488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

here is my code:

```
case 'cursedimage':
                    fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/cursedimages/random/.json').then(response => {
                    let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    var image = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
                    let permalink = content[0].data.children[0].data.permalink;
                    let memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
                    let memeImage = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
                    let memeTitle = content[0].data.children[0].data.title;
                    let memeUpvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.ups;
                    let memeNumComments = content[0].data.children[0].data.num_comments;
                    const cursedembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setTitle(content[0].data.children[0].data.title)
                    .setURL(`${memeUrl}`)
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`)
                    .setTimestamp()
                message.channel.send(cursedembed);
                });
                break
```

Comment: If you do `console.log(response.body)` what does it print?

Comment: You need to return the JSON in this manner: `fetch("URL").then(response => response.json()).then(body => /* your code */).catch(e => console.error(e));`

Comment: Also remove the `JSON.parse` invocation from your code.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment it prints:

````
Gunzip {
  _writeState: Uint32Array(2) [ 0, 0 ],
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  readable: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
    end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: bound _close] },
    unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
    error: [ [Function: onerror], [Function] ],
    close: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onclose] },
    finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onfinish] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 6,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: {
      next: null,
      entry: null,
      finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish]
    }
  },
  writable: true,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  _transformState: {
    afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
    needTransform: false,
    transforming: false,
    writecb: null,
    writechunk: null,
    writeencoding: null
  },
  _hadError: false,
  bytesWritten: 0,
  _handle: Zlib {
    onerror: [Function: zlibOnError],
    [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular]
  },
  _outBuffer: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 16334 more bytes>,
  _outOffset: 0,
  _chunkSize: 16384,
  _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
  _finishFlushFlag: 2,
  _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
  _info: undefined,
  _level: -1,
  _strategy: 0,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this piece of Code ?

```js
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/cursedimages/random/.json').then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
  let content = response.data;
  var image = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
  let permalink = content[0].data.children[0].data.permalink;
  let memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
  let memeImage = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
  let memeTitle = content[0].data.children[0].data.title;
  let memeUpvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.ups;
  let memeNumComments = content[0].data.children[0].data.num_comments;
  const cursedembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle(content[0].data.children[0].data.title)
    .setURL(`${memeUrl}`)
    .setImage(image)
    .setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`)
    .setTimestamp()
  message.channel.send(cursedembed);
});
```

Comment: I tried that code and it brought up an error saying
`(node:13064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`